# Tomcat 7: How do I specify Database resource when making connection to Microsoft Access

Tags: java, ms-access, tomcat, jdbc, tomcat7

I know how to specific datasource connection pooling to a mysql server in Tomcat 7, add

```
<Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        name="jdbc/TestDB"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"
        username="mysql_user"
        password="mypassword123"
/>
```

to my `META-INF/context.xml`,

1. Can anyone show me how to do this to `Microsoft Access`?
2. Do I need a JDBC - ODBC bridge to make connection from my Java web app to Microsoft Access?

**UPDATE**: This is my attempt, but I ran into `SQLException`

```
<Resource  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           name="jdbc-odbc/qtl"
           maxActive="100"
           maxIdle="30"
           maxWait="10000"
           factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
           driverClassName="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"
           url="jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=/Users/KingdomHeart/resources/db.mdb"               
           />
```

When I do this, I got `WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.sql.SQLException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver`

**UPDATE 2:**: I tried to write a separate program in effort to make connection to Microsoft Access db. I got `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` Here is my code. It must be that I need a `jar` driver in my class path, do I not?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String fileName = "/Users/KingdomHeart/resources/MyTable.mdb";
        String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=";
        database += fileName + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=true";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
        System.out.println("here");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestJdbcOdbc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestJdbcOdbc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a URL like this:

```
jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=c:\\path\\your-access-database.mdb
```

The JDBC driver class is `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` (at least it was when I last used it; that was back in 2004).

I prefer this style because it eliminates the step of creating an ODBC data source.  It keeps the precise location of the file inside the Java deployment.

Yes, you need the JDBC-ODBC bridge (unless you bought a commercial JDBC driver).

You should be aware of the pitfalls of using Access in a multi-user environment:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa167840(v=office.11).aspx

My personal recommendation would be to use MySQL or PostgreSQL instead of Access.

Here's something else you might want to read about setting up a JNDI data source on Tomcat:

http://craicpropagation.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-use-same-jndi-resource-name-on.html

Comment: Thank you so much, I dont like Access as well, but no choice here. Is the `driverClassName` `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver`? and is there a `factory`?

Comment: Factory for....?  Do you mean for the database connection?  I hope you're using a JNDI connection pool.  If that's what you mean by factory, the answer is "yes".  That's part of the Tomcat configuration - but then you already know that, since you have a META-INF/context.xml.

Comment: yeah, I am using JNDI connection pooling, I have one more question if you dont mind helping me a bit more, what should I use for Jdbc-Odbc bridge? I goole and see one for easysoft, http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/jdbc_odbc_bridge/, but not a lot, is it this right? does Sun/Oracle not produce JDBC-ODBC bridge?

Comment: No worries.  The Sun JDBC-ODBC class that I cited above ships with the JDK, so you don't need to have anything above and beyond the JDK to use it.

Comment: I got `WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.sql.SQLException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver`. I am using JDK 6 with Tomcat 7 and `mysql-connector-java-5.1.15.jar` I post a new `Resource` on my post, do you think you can take a look?

Comment: I don't see a drive letter on your path to the database.  Leave Tomcat out of it for a moment.  Can you write a simple main method that runs on the command line and connects to the database?  Try that.

Comment: I have write a separate main program try making db connection to Access DB, and I still getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver`, I updated my original post with some more code in `UPDATE 2`. Can you take a look if you have some times?

Comment: Open your runtime JAR and see if it's in there.

Comment: Acctually, this might due to the fact that I am using 64 bits JDK, I am switching to my 32 bits window machine, and does not give me an Exception anymore. Let me write some more code, and I will let you know.

Comment: Yup this seems to be the case here. Apparently, 64 bits JDK does not contain `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver`